# Need a way to execute a powershell script asynchronosly

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, visual-studio, powershell, async-await

On a Windows 7 PC, I'm building a Windows Forms application with

- Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise
- VB.net
- .Net Framework 4.5.2
- PowerShell 5.0

The application involves multithreading because it has an embedded PowerShell script that takes a fairly long time to run. Embedded here means that the `fillListOfStringVarAsync()` function (shown below) builds a string variable with the PowerShell script text. A second thread runs `fillListOfStringVarAsync()` and the main thread places the returned data from this function on a main form control. I first used the BackgroundWorker approach, with the DoWork handler, etc. This works perfectly. Then I read about the newer async / await approach; I rebuilt everything using async / await and I hit a wall. This sample

```vb
Imports System.Management.Automation

Public Class demo

    Private Async Sub form_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        '   Some statements

        Dim listOfStringVar As List(Of String) = Await fillListOfStringVarAsync()

        '   Some statements that use the
        '
        '       listOfStringVar
        '
        '   value

    End Sub

    Private Async Function fillListOfStringVarAsync() As Task(Of List(Of String))

        Dim scriptText As String = "#PowerShell 5.0 script, known to work"
        Dim stringListVar As New List(Of String)

        Dim psInstance As PowerShell = PowerShell.Create().AddScript(scriptText)
        Dim async As IAsyncResult = psInstance.BeginInvoke()        'await won't work here

        For Each obj As PSObject In psInstance.EndInvoke(async)     'await won't work here

            stringListVar.Add(obj.ToString)

        Next

        Return stringListVar

    End Function

End Class
```

shows the basic engineering of the rebuild, with async / await. The problem: inside the `fillListOfStringVarAsync()` function, the psInstance object - which has the PowerShell script - needs an await expression, but I don't know the correct syntax for this. Visual Studio green-underlines the function name `fillListOfStringVarAsync()` with a warning that

> This async method lacks 'Await' operators and so will run asynchronously etc. etc. etc.

The app compiles, but without the await operator in `fillListOfStringVarAsync()`, the main form disappears until the secondary thread completes and returns its data. [This page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674902.aspx) and [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.powershell.endinvoke(v=vs.85).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1), both from Microsoft, brought me the closest. I looked all over StackOverflow but no luck.

Comment: Just in general, you should do a callback function, and get rid of the await in your form load... But the await basically stops your load.

Comment: You are awaiting the call in Form_Load, then you shouldn't await it deeper in the call stack. The point of [async/await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx) is to be able to call long running operations from the UI thread, but not block the UI. That's it. The first await spawns a non-UI thread so you don't need to await another call from there. You could leverage multi-threading at that point but with a different vehicle such as [Task Parallel Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: `I first used the BackgroundWorker approach, with the DoWork handler, etc. This works perfectly. Then I read about the newer async / await approach...` I must say, also, that you had something working perfectly, so why change it?

Comment: Thanks to you both. Your advice and Mr. Harmon's below nailed it. The BackgroundWorker machinery is really complex compared to async, so even though BW worked well, async worked better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 
    await Task.Run(() => YourMethod());

I'm not sure that will help though. At least in web apps, awaiting will still stop your form from showing up until the async method has completed.

Comment: Thank you! I changed the function call as you suggested and I scrapped all the async / await stuff in fillListOfStringVarAsync(). It worked!

You are a Jedi . . .